How to resolve error "A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable"?
I received this error while building the app.
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: 
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable



In my main app i have imported an another module implementation project(':app1') in my project.
In my app level build.gradle i am using one library, and also in my imported module i am using a third party library which is build upon that library i am using in the app level, seems that can be the problem of duplicate class found, as well as i am using these lines in my gradle.properties
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

I am looking for a solution to get rid of this problem of duplicate class. i am also open to suggestions..
Thanks in advance, if anyone can help me to find a way out of this..
